# Making a roulette game, keep getting error in python

Tags: python, python-3.7

I'm fairly new to python, so sorry if this is a bit basic.
I have undertaken making a roulette game to improve my programming skills and have come across a very strange error. At first, when I wanted to print the player's balance at the end of the roll and once the results were checked, it printed out the array that holds all the red numbers. I looked over the code that was defining the `balance` variable but there was nothing that looked like it might affect it. 
I for some reason thought that defining `balance` as `int(100)` instead of `100` might fix it but i instead got this error:`TypeError: checkresults() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bet'` I deleted the `int` in `balance` and it still persisted. For those wondering, I make `checkresults` use `bet` and have even tried moving the place where it goes in the list of variables used but still no fix. `balance = checkresults(bet, bet_choice, number, balance, red, black, green, first, second, third)` as you can see, it's the first variable it uses. The full code for `checkresults` is here:

```
def checkresults(self, bet_choice, number, balance, red, black, green, first, second, third, bet):
if bet_choice == "number":
    if bet == number:
        balance = balance + (bet_amount*14)
        print("You Won!")
    else:
        print("You Lost")
elif bet_choice == "colour":
    if bet == "red":
        if number in red:
            balance = balance + (bet_amount*2)
            print("You Won!")
        else:
            print("You Lost")
    elif bet == "black":
        if number in black:
            balance = balance + (bet_amount*2)
            print("You Won!")
        else:
            print("You Lost")
    else:
        if number in green:
            balance = balance + (bet_amount*14)
            print("You Won!")
        else:
            print("You Lost")
elif bet_choice == "third":
    if bet == "1st":
        if number in first:
            balance = balance + (bet_amount*3)
            print("You Won!")
        else:
            print("You Lost")
    elif bet == "2nd":
        if number in second:
            balance = balance + (bet_amount*3)
            print("You Won!")
        else:
            print("You Lost")
    elif bet == "3rd":
        if number in third:
            balance = balance + (bet_amount*3)
            print("You Won!")
        else:
            print("You Lost")
return balance
```

the value for bet is decided by this:

```
def choosebet():
bet_choice = input("Would you like to bet on a number, colour, or a third? ")
if bet_choice == "number":
    bet = int(input("Which number would you like to bet on? "))
elif bet_choice == "colour":
    bet = input("Which colour would you like to bet on?")
else:
    bet = input("Which third would you like to bet on?")
return bet, bet_choice
```

Comment: It would help if you could post what values are being fed into checkresults().

Comment: It seems that you have a mandatory `bet` argument at the end of your function declaration that you are not passing a value to.

Comment: Ohad Chaet i put a print statement in front of the checkresults and bet does have a value as it printed correctly

Comment: Hi @RandxmStranger, is very important ask questions in the right way in order to get a high quality response. As @Joshua and @Ohad suggest, you have a problem with the  `checkresults` call. For that we suspect that here is not important the body of this function. Please edit your answer including the `checkresults` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `self` in the defining part of the `checkresults` code, from a previous error. I deleted `self` and 1: it fixed the new error and 2: the old error didn't come back.

Answer (score 0):

`checkresults` as defined takes eleven arguments - it looks like the first parameter is supposed to be an instance of the class that `checkresults` is defined *in* - when you call the method directly without reference to the instance *it* thinks you did not pass the eleventh argument.

Answer (score -1):

I am doing the exact same thing. I started python about two and a half months ago, and have been working on a roulette game for the past month.

This doesn't answer the question, but I had similar issues when I started. If your intent is to build out the entire game, the path you are on is not sustainable. There will be too many elif statements and you will want to rip your hair out (as I did).

What I ended up doing was putting all the "constants" in dictionaries. By constants I mean the numbers in each bet (red vs black, odd vs even, etc), the numbers on the wheel, and the payouts for each bet.

From there you can use dictionary methods to lookup up the winning numbers in the bet dictionaries (i.e. is this a red or black number) and then compare that to a dictionary of placed bets, and if there is a match, look up the payout for the bet.

Good luck!